# php abstract class inheritance error with no abstract method to inherit

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, decorator, abstract

I'm a relative newbie to OOP, and I am getting this error on a learning exercise.

```
Class contains 6 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
```

the error is being thrown from a child class of an abstract class, implementing an interface.  I understand that children of an abstract class must implement all abstract methods, but I am not declaring any abstract methods in the parent class or the interface.  Shouldn't I only be getting this error if I am not including, in the child class, a declared abstract method from the abstract class or interface?

child class:

```
class OuterViewDecorator extends AbstractViewDecorator
    {
    const DEFAULT_TEMPLATE = "/var/www/portfolio/simple-php/templates/layout.php";

    public function render() {
        $data["innerview"] = $this->view->render();
        return $this->renderTemplate($data);
    }
}
```

parent class:

```
abstract class AbstractViewDecorator implements ViewInterface
{
    const DEFAULT_TEMPLATE = "default.php";
    protected $template = self::DEFAULT_TEMPLATE;
    protected $view;    

    public function __construct(ViewInterface $view)
    {
        $this->view = $view;
    }   

    public function render()
    {
        return $this->view->render();
    }   

    public function renderTemplate(array $data = array())
    {
        extract($data);
        ob_start();
        $template = include $this->template;
        return ob_get_clean($template);
    }
}
```

interface:

```
interface ViewInterface
{
    public function setTemplate($template);
    public function getTemplate();
    public function __set($field, $value);
    public function __get($field);
    public function __isset($field);
    public function __unset($field);
    public function render();
}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: You are probably safe in removing the __set __get __isset and __unset methods from the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying it is implementing an interface.

Between all of the inheriting classes must implement all of the interface methods 
So for example your `AbstractViewDecorator` could implement 2 of the methods, and `OuterViewDecorator` could implement the last 4,  or `OuterViewDecorator` could do all 6.. As long as all of the methods are implements in the class inheritance chain.

Comment: not necessarily either/or but before you create a concrete instance. For example it is completely valid for AbstractViewDecorator to implement half of them and OuterViewDecorator to implement the other half.

Comment: lol thanks, didn't think all the interface methods needed to be used